# Click listener for drawableleft in EditText in Android?

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener

Is it possible to add a `OnClickListener` to on a drawable that is declared in designer as `drawableleft`

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_password"
```

Or is there any way to add a `ImageView` on the left side of that `EditText`

Comment: You could use a `LinearLayout` with two children, and `ImageView` and an `EditText`

Answer (score 1):

There is more elegant way:
Don't use `android:drawableStart` or `android:drawableLeft` in the `TextInputEditText`.

Instead you can use:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:endIconMode="custom"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/..."
```

and then use the `endIconOnClickListener`:

```
textInputLayout.setStartIconOnClickListener {
  // Respond to end icon presses
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65940540/13545849

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by a RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_iamge"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_id"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Your text" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And add `onClickListener` to the `ImageView` in your code.

Comment: I think it's a proper answer for the question "Or is there any way to add a ImageView on the left side of that EditText"

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the OnTouchListener and add your click action.
I used the below helper class. `onDrawableClick` returns:
true if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise

```
public abstract class DrawableClickListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
public static final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
public static final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
public static final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
public static final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

private final int drawableIndex;

public DrawableClickListener(int index) {
    drawableIndex = index;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) view;
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (event.getRawX() >= (textView.getRight() - textView.getCompoundDrawables()[drawableIndex].getBounds().width())) {
            return onDrawableClick();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public abstract boolean onDrawableClick();
```

}