# An OnClickListener for DrawableLeft in an EditText?

Tags: java, android, drawable

I am trying create an `OnTouchListener` to my `editText` ("search").

I took the code from post : [Click listener for drawableleft in EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650575/click-listener-for-drawableleft-in-edittext-in-android)

(Along with other posts) I am getting an error saying

> Custom view EditText has set OnTouchListener called on it but does not
>   override PerformClick

Not quite sure where to go from here, as there is not much written about this that I can find. Thanks from your help!

```
search.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;

                if(event.getX() <= (search.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_LEFT].getBounds().width()))
                {
                    // your action here
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can suppress the error by using `@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")`

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47107105/android-button-has-setontouchlistener-called-on-it-but-does-not-override-perform?rq=1) question for more information on your error.

Comment: Thank you! Problem now is I have drawablePadding set to 20dp so if i click on the drawable in the EditText the keyboard pops up instead of handling the onTouch for the drawable...