# Setting on click listener to TextInputEditText drawable Right/End android studio

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I am having a Text Input Layout with Text Input Edit Text inside. The Text Input Edit Text has a Drawable at the end. What i want to achieve is make the drawable at the end do something when it is clicked for example show a Toast message

Below is my XML Code

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_toast"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:padding="3dp">

            <!--android:maxLength="13"-->
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_toast"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_calendar"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_calendar"
                android:hint="@string/date_from"
                android:inputType="date" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

How can i achieve this

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't use `android:drawableRight` or `android:drawableEnd` in the `TextInputEditText`.

Instead you can use:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:endIconMode="custom"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/..."
```

and then use the `endIconOnClickListener`:

```
textInputLayout.setEndIconOnClickListener {
  // Respond to end icon presses
}
```